# Finding outliers with IsolationForest in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

i want to find outliers in my dataframe. 
I wrote a code that will tell me if my input values are outliers or not but I cant find a way to check if my data contains outliers or not. Also, i think that my code does not work good because it says that these values `[1,4,64]` are not outliers and I think that they are.

```
   first  second  third  result
0      1       2      7    3.00
1     28      85     74    0.04
2      5       2      3    3.00
3      6       4      8    4.00
4      3       6      2    3.00
5      5       8      4    5.00
6      4       3      7    6.00
7      2       5      1    6.00
8      7       7    533    0.80
9      5       3      6    9.00
```

For example, you can clearly see that values in 1st row and 8th row are outliers.
This is the code that I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest  

df = pd.DataFrame({'first': [1,28,5,6,3,5,4,2,7,5],
                   'second': [2,85,2,4,6,8,3,5,7,3],
                   'third': [7,74,3,8,2,4,7,1,533,6],
                   'result': [3,0.04,3,4,3,5,6,6,0.8,9]})

print(df)

x = df.iloc[:,:-1]
print(x)

isolation_forest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100, behaviour="new",
                                   contamination='auto')
model = isolation_forest.fit(x)

list_of_val = [[1,35,3], [3,4,5], [1,4,64]]

for val in list_of_val:

    outlier = isolation_forest.predict([val])
    print(outlier)

    if outlier[0] == -1:
        print('Values', val, 'are outliers')

    else:
        print('Values', val, 'are not outliers')
```

I would be very thankfull if you tell me why my code does not detect values `[1,4,64]` as outlier, and If you tell me how can I get `outlier column` in my dataframe that will have values `outlier` and `not outlier` next to values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a way

```
isolation_forest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100, behaviour="new",
                                   contamination='auto')
model = isolation_forest.fit(x)
df['outliers'] = model.predict(x)
print(df)
```